# How can I optimize this android code?

Tags: java, android

I want to parse jsonarray which has uncertain length,

- if this array's length is 0,then children are null;
- if this array's length is 1,then children0 has some value,and others
  are null;
- if this array's length is 2,then children0 and children2 have some
  values, and children3 is null;
- if this array's length >= 3,then children0 and children1 and
  children2 have values.

How can I optimize this code?

That's all...

It's my first time to ask question on stack overflow.

I'm so sorry for my poor English...

```
String children0 = null;
String children1 = null;
String children2 = null;

if (chArray.length() > 2) {
    children0 = value0;
    children1 = value1;
    children2 = value2;
} else if (chArray.length() == 2) {
    children0 = value0;
    children1 = value1;
} else if (chArray.length() == 1) {
    children0 = value0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an array

```
String[] childrens = new String[3];

for(int i=0; i<chArray.length() && i<3; i++)
    childrens[i] = value[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the `switch` for this

```
switch(chArray.length){
    default: // > 2 because every lower cases are defined after!
        children2 = value2;
    case 2:
        children1 = value1;
    case 1:
        children0 = value0;
    case 0: //error check if the array is empty before (this is ugly like this ;) )
}
```

Without breaks, it will place itself in the right position depending on the length of the array received then execute the following line.